# Update object with model form inside the view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I need to update the object with its model form and passed the instance as described in the [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method). However I am having these problems when saving the form:

1. When I change the `title` and submit the form, it gives me an error that the `image` field is required and image field gets blank. However when the `image` is changed, the title field is not blank and it does not give any error.
2. If everything works and submits the form, it creates a new `snap` object instead of updating the `instance` object.

In the views I tried using both the `obj.save()` and `obj.update()`, but nothing helped. Please help me how to solve this problem. I will really appreciate your help Thank you.

form:

```
class SnapForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Snap
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'image', 'upload_date']
```

view:

```
def admin_snap_settings(request, snap_id):
    if not request.user.is_admin:
        return render(request, 'admin_login_invalid.html')
    else:
        instance = Snap.objects.get(id=snap_id)
        if request.user == instance.user:
            if request.method == "POST":
                form = SnapForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance)
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/custom123user/admin/snapview')
            else:
                form = SnapForm(instance=instance)
            return render(request, 'admin_snap_settings.html', {
                'form': form
            })
        else:
            return render(request, 'wrong_user.html')
```

Comment: Sorry, a bit vague to me: is your view an edit operation? Have you tried to initialize your modelform with your model?

Comment: @Wtower Yes, `form = SnapForm(instance=instance)`, where instance is the object with reference to the `snap_id`.

Comment: Ah yes I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of debugging and scratching head... I realized that the url of the  `action` for the form was pointing to `admin_snap_add()` view and not to the `admin_snap_settings()` view.

Hope this will help someone so dumb as me. If you guys want me to delete this question please inform me. Thank you for your time.